# Explain like I'm 5. Alternate access Mapping problem

Tags: iis, alternate-access-mapping, host-named

Assume http: has 2 forward slashes

I have a web application: http:/spintranet.domain.something-xxx.org (This is the host name, this is what is typed into the url)

I have a dns record for http:/spintranet
I have disabled IIS default website
This is an intranet

I need users to type http://spintranet, and access the web application.
I am going crazy over this, everything I try to do in Alternate Access Mappings, throws errors.

Comment: what error you getting?

Answer (score 1):

- Do you have a DNS entry to point spintranet to that server's IP address? Try to ping spintranet and see if the IP (if any) that you get back is the SharePoint WFE server.
- Also, you can choose to add the IIS binding http:/spintranet to the IIS site from IIS Manager.

Go to IIS Manager -> Select the SharePoint site -> Edit Bindings -> add the binding to port 80 -> click ok.

Also make sure that users have http:/spintranet in their trusted sites.
IE -> Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet

Comment: The entry point is pointed to the WFE correctly. I don't know what you mean add the binding to port 80. the Type is http. the hostname is spintranet.domain.something-xxx.org. IP address is all unassigned, the port is 80.

Comment: When I put the binding on just port 80, so i delete the host name, and i try to access http://spintranet. I recieve error 404